# PHPMailer not delivering email with URL in body

Tags: php, email, cakephp, phpmailer

I have configured my Cake PHP web app to send email through PHP Mailer class and that has been working in perfection.

However, everytime I form a new mail that contains text in the form of URL (even if incomplete) of .net domain the message isn't delivered, with no visible error in debug, PHP Mailer always sends message with success.

Relevant code:

```
$textMessage = "This remains unchanged!";
$mail->Subject = "Always the same subject!";
$mail->Body    = $htmlMessage;
$mail->AltBody = $textMessage;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  return array('type' => "error", 'message' => 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
} else {
  return array('type' => "success", 'message' =>  "Message sent!");
}
```

Working values for $message var where emails get delivered:

```
 $htmlMessage = "<p>Message sent from your site at <a href=\"https://www.uncarved.com\">Uncarved.com</a>.</p>";

 $htmlMessage = "<p>Message sent from your site at <a href=\"https://www.uncarved.anything\">Uncarved.anything</a>.</p>";
```

Values that result in the mail is sent but not delivered:

```
 $htmlMessage = "<p>Message sent from your site at <a href=\"https://www.uncarved.com\">Uncarved.net</a>.</p>";

 $htmlMessage = "<p>Message sent from your site at <a href=\"https://www.uncarved.net\">Uncarved.com</a>.</p>";
```

Note: I also have content from form post that is included in the message. The message is not delivered if this content containts a .net literal.

I am sending to hotmail and gmail as recipient emails, and the result is the same. I presume the inbound email servers do not exclude messages with ".net" in its content, and so I am clueless at this point as to where the problem is.

I would much appreciate any ideas towards a solution.

Comment: There is a distinct difference between "not sent" and "not received". Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and watch the SMTP conversation.

Comment: I did use the debug, and the SMTP connection is performed fully. By not delivered I meant the email isn't received. The debug log is the same for both cases, regardless of being received or not.
However, it seems to be happening only when the url (partial or full) in the body relates to sites that are marked as unsafe by the browser. I'm investigating this possibility.

Comment: Right, so this isn't a PHP problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an email problem. I'm going to confirm this is the case, and close the issue. Thank you for the input!